# How to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to read from pom file inside another xml file?

Tags: spring, maven, applicationcontext

i want to use **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** to read from pom file inside the **applicationContext.xml** file as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="${project.groupId}"/>
```

taking in consideration that **pom file** has the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
```

here's the **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**  configuration:

```
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:oauth_consumer.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

issue: PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is not able to replace the value in applicationContext.xml.

please advise how to get that to work. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem, the applicationContext was under **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF** but it had to be under **src/main/resources** in order to work.